# Keep expanded menu open when going to new page

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I have created a simple accordion menu(sort of), the first problem I encountered was when going to a page I wanted to make the respective anchor to be active, I have solved it by using a script, but another problem is when going to another page from an expanded menu, I want the expanded menu to be open when I reach the opened page. I have tried many methods, but it's not working.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U8J6A/

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">index</a></li>
    <li><a href="forum.html">forum</a></li>
    <li id="submenu"><span class="s_act">links</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index1.html">index</a></li>
            <li><a href="index2.html">index</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
//To make the current link active
$(function(){
    var sPath = window.location.pathname;
    var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    $('a[href="'+ sPage +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});

//Toggling the submenu
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submenu ul").hide();

    $("#submenu").click(function () {

        $("span.s_act").addClass("submenu_act");
        $("#submenu ul").show();

     });

});
```

Comment: Do you have a common master page or do you repeat your navigation on every page?

Comment: would that be a .NET Web Forms Master page?

Comment: I dont know too much about that,i'm just a web designer who knows only html,css stuffs..

Comment: no worries, I was just wondering

Comment: What you need to do is load your html pages in via AJAX. What you are experiencing is the fact the web sites are stateless.

Comment: Do `index1.html` and `index2.html` pages have navigation on them?

Comment: What? Do you mean,does index1.html and index2.html have submenu? If yes,no they dont have submenu. Also sidemenu is common for all pages.

Comment: Ok cool, ya that's what I was asking. I will add an AJAX solution as an answer then and you can see if ya can get it working

Answer (score 0):

Use following jQuery on your master page :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageTitle = window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\/([^/]*)/, "$1");

        $('#menu li').removeClass("active");
        $("#submenu ul").hide();

        ///// Apply active class to selected page link
        $('#menu li a').each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() == pageTitle.toLocaleLowerCase())
            {

                  $(this).closest('li').closest('li').addClass('active');
                  if($(this).parent().closest('li').attr('class') == 'submenu')  
                      $("#submenu ul").show();

             }
        });

});
```

Comment: I replaced my entire script with yours,it works but it removes the active class when in home page,also the menu is expanded in home page,i only want it expanded when it is clicked or a submenu under it is clicked.

Comment: Yes this is expected because home page link is on level l. Check this edited answer.

Comment: Menu is still expanded in home page,it should only be activated when it is clicked or a subpage under it is open.

Comment: Which css class do you use to expand the menu?

Comment: I use .click() function to expand the submenu when clicking and on pageload it is hidden by the .hide() function,Please refer my script in first post.

Comment: Now i cant even toggle the submenu when clicking.

Comment: include the you click function inside document.ready function.

Comment: Tried it,but when going to subpage,the menu is not open.Are you even testing the code you are posting here? o_O

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44639/discussion-between-irfan-tahirkheli-and-sharath-daniel)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AJAX solution, which will help your navigation maintain its state when various pages are called:

Rough HTML markup:

```
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">index</a></li>
        <li><a href="forum.html">forum</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><span class="s_act">links</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index1.html">index</a></li>
                <li><a href="index2.html">index</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
      <!--Page Content Goes Here-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submenu ul").hide();
    $("#submenu").click(function () {
        $("span.s_act").addClass("submenu_act");
        $("#submenu ul").show();
     });
     $("#submenu ul li a").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var page = $(this).attr('href');
         $.get(page, function(html){
            $('#content').html(html);
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: I tried this,i cant navigate to subpages also it doesn't make the home page link active when i'm in that page.